# Database Migration Laravel 5.2 Arrange Table

Tags: laravel, migration

I have a create_users_table at the top and with foreign key to roles table but the location of roles table is at the bottom of create_users_table. So what happen is the create_users table can't see the roles table because it's not yet created. See attached image:

[image]

Do I need to recreate a users table so that it will come up below to roles table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its just a beginning of the project and if you are **not using database migrations versioning** yet you could just rename the datetime timestamp at migrations filename to rearrange the migrations. something like this would rearrange migrations to the required order. see i changed the year of `2016_08_13_001252_create_roles_table.php` to `2014_08_13_001252_create_roles_table.php`.

```
2014_08_13_001252_create_roles_table.php
2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php
2016_08_08_005720_create_messages_table.php
```

migrations run in the datetime order of the filenames. Only the new migrations are run at each run. so, if you bring such changes to the files like renaming the file you need to drop database and create again, then run the migrations.

sometime after doing this you **might** need to run following commands in the project
`composer dump-autoload` and/or `php artisan clear-compiled`.

**if you are running the migrations verisoning?**

migrations are something related to databases and its not meant for dropping all the tables and recreating each and every time when you need to bring a change. If the database is live or if you have completed major database design you could use versioning. one of the purpose of migrations made in that way (datetime order and only new ones are migrated each time) is that only changes are brought to the old migrations created.

Comment: Thanks bro! You save me from installing DBAL. That's what I really need.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to recreate a users table so that it will come up below to
>   roles table?

You can't add a foreign key to a table that does not yet exist. If you want to manage your database through migrations, you do need to put them in the right order.

However, you can also add it as a separate migration, so that you have

1. create users table
2. create roles table
3. alter users table to add role_id field and foreign key

That way you don't have to rearrange existing migrations if you e.g. need to make changes to the database mid-project.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so that would be the process but wasn't really sure. Thanks.